# IOS/Objective-c: Return value from completion block or closure asynchronously to calling function

Tags: ios, objective-c, closures

Because of the asynchronous nature of closures or completion blocks, I gather it is not possible to "return" a value directly from one.  In my UI, however, for a chat app, it is acceptable--and in fact necessary to wait for the response. My question, therefore, is what is the best way to hold up any activity until you have a response, and second, return the response to calling method.

This is what I would like to do which I don't think you can do...

```
(NSString*) getStringFromRemoteResource {

    [self goGetString:^(NSString *string,NSError *error){
   NSLog(@"retrieved string is%@",string);
        return string;//NOT ALLOWED
    }];
}
```

//On the other hand, you can do this where the return is void

```
(void) getStringFromRemoteResource {

    [self goGetString:^(NSString *string,NSError *error){
   NSLog(@"string is%@",string);
        [self doSomethingWithString];
    }];
}
```

In my code the manager which calls the method above has to return a value.

```
        (NSString*) chatManager {
        [self getStringFromRemoteResource];
//do other stuff
    return string;
        }
```

So my question is after calling getStringFromRemoteResource how do I get the result back to the manageChat to return it to the UI. Or what does doSomethingWithString look like?  I don't want to fundamentally change chatManager as it does a bunch of other things as well.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: The manager would pass in its own block to be executed once the string is received. You have to adopt the asynchronous pattern from the top down.

Comment: The manager is actually a sharedInstance called from another class and manager's job is to get and return string.  Would I have to write the value back to to the other class separately, or could there be a way to somehow get value back into manager to return or pause manager until it's received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the course of any asynchronous call you can't have any method in the hierarchy that returns a value directly unless you block that thread , but you need

```
-(void)chatManager:(void (^)(NSString*))completed {

    [self getStringFromRemoteResource:^(NSString *str) {
        completed(str);
    }];
}

-(void)getStringFromRemoteResource:(void (^)(NSString*))comp{

    [self goGetString:^(NSString *string,NSError *error){
        comp(string);
    }];
}
```

**OR**

```
-(void)chatManager:(void (^)(NSString*))completed {

    [self goGetString:^(NSString *string,NSError *error){
        completed(string);
    }];
}
```

here `chatManager` is only a wrapper for organizing reasons that enable you to have access to it's methods anywhere instead of duplicating them everywhere , but it has to have this structure

Comment: Ok.  So you are saying you can never have an asynchronous call that directly returns a value such as -(NSString*)returnRemoteValue.  The complicating factor here is that the manager is called from another class, so I have to get the value back to the other class.  But that is not part of this question so I will work on that separately.

Comment: asynchronous tasks always attached with UI dimming such as showing activity indicator the user expects that